# Use of express-basic auth to simple prompt authentication in react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a simple prompt authentication for my react app and I've this file server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;



app.use(basicAuth({
    challenge: true,
    users: { 'me': 'openforme' }
}))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
```

I want that when the user and pass are correct app use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')))
```

to see my web page

Comment: Nice. So, what is your problem?

Comment: That not works, only appear the prompt, and I want to redirect to main page

Comment: I'm trying this tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-secure-react-app-login-authentication/

Comment: Enter `me` as username and `openforme` as password when you see the prompt.

Comment: Yes but not redirects anywhere

Comment: Where you want to go?

Comment: I want that once the user and password have been passed correctly, it loads the react app

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/index.html`